# Duplicates on runtime MVC4 Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, many-to-many, entity-framework-5, updates

I get this strange "error". When i run my app (edit action i.e update) i get duplicate values stored in my dB. If i use the debugger, step by step, its working (no duplicates)...

*It's a Many-to-Many Relationship so don't bother the Courses NULL value in the images, just trying to figure things out...*

All Help is appreciated!

> ```
>   [HttpPost]
>     public ActionResult Edit(CourseStudentViewModel model)
>     {
>         var course = db.Courses
>             .Where(c => c.Id == model.CourseId)
>             .Single();
>
>         if (ModelState.IsValid)
>         {
>             course.Name = model.CourseName;
>             course.Description = model.CourseDescription;
>             course.Students = model.Students;
>
>             if(course.Id != 0) {
>                 db.Entry(course).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
>             }
>             else {
>                 db.Courses.Add(course);
>             }
>             db.SaveChanges();
>             return RedirectToAction("Index");
>         }
>         //modelstate not valid, display form
>         return View(model);
>     }
> ```
>
> I get my viewModel back. All good.
>   [image: My view Model that i get back]

My Old values from dB. I want to update this data. So everything is still good...

[image]

My old values are updated to my new Values. Great!

[image]

---

**Ok everything works great IF I step with debugger like this. But if i run the app i will get duplicates.... Anyone?**

**New content:**

My Edit-view

> @model ValueInjecter.Web.Models.CourseStudentViewModel
>
> @{
>       ViewBag.Title = "Edit"; }
>
> Edit Course
>
> @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
>       
>           @Html.HiddenFor(c => Model.CourseId)
>           @Html.LabelFor(c => Model.CourseName)
>           @Html.EditorFor(c => Model.CourseName)
>
> ```
>     @Html.LabelFor(c => Model.CourseDescription)
>     @Html.EditorFor(c => Model.CourseDescription)
> </div>
>
> <hr />
> <h2>Students</h2>
>
> <div class="editor-field">
>     @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Students.Count(); i++)
>     {
>         <div style="border: dotted 1px; padding: 5px; margin: 10px;">
>             @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.Students[i].Id)
>
>             @Html.LabelFor(s => s.Students[i].Name[i + 1])
>             @Html.EditorFor(s => s.Students[i].Name)
>         </div>
>     }
> </div>
> <p>
>     Number of Students: 
> <b>@Html.DisplayFor(s => Model.StudentCount)</b>
> </p>
> <hr />
> <p>
>     <input type="submit" value="Save" />
> </p> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured out the solution of my problem. Of course much easier than first thought.

> [HttpPost]
>
> ```
>     public ActionResult Edit(CourseStudentViewModel model)
>     {
>
>         if (ModelState.IsValid)
>         {
>             var course = db.Courses.Find(model.CourseId);
>             course.Name = model.CourseName;
>             course.Description = model.CourseDescription;
>
>             if(model.Students != null)
>             {
>                 foreach (var item in model.Students)
>                 {
>                     db.Entry(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
>                 }
>             }
>
>             if(course.Id != 0) {
>                 db.Entry(course).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
>             }
>             else {
>                 db.Courses.Add(course);
>             }
>             db.SaveChanges();
>             return RedirectToAction("Index");
>         }
>         //modelstate not valid, display form
>         return View(model);
>     }
> ```

Still using the view ive pasted **above**.

Answer (score 0):

It probably works in the debugger because by inspecting `course.Students` collection in a property watch window you trigger actually a second database query (after the query that loads the `course`) due to *lazy loading* of the `Students` collection. (Your `Course.Students` collection is most likely declared as `virtual`.) If you run without debugger no lazy loading occurs and `course.Students` stays empty.

You can force that the `course.Students` collection is always loaded by using *eager loading* instead of lazy loading (which also saves the second database roundtrip):

```
var course = db.Courses
    .Include(c => c.Students)
    .Where(c => c.Id == model.CourseId)
    .Single();
```

Honestly I have no clue why your code works correctly with the loaded collection (in the debugger) and why it works at all. Assigning a complete detached collection like this: `course.Students = model.Students`, and then just setting the state of the parent to `Modified` is normally not enough to update a child collection.

But I see `"ValueInjecter"` in your screenshots. Maybe there is some automatic mapping magic happening that does (accidentally?) the right thing to get a working update.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer. My collection (course.Students) is not empty. Its duplicated. Old values from db and new values from UI (textboxes). I've added my view. I appreciated if u can give me some guidance cause i cant get this many-to-many relation to work... and the valueinjecter you see is just the namespace. When i created the project i was first trying to work with automapping.

Comment: @JeppePepp: Did you try it with the `Include` in my answer above? Didn't it work?

Comment: it is not possible to use lambda inside the include extension. You can only use a string path. So nope, it did not work. Thx for your time tho. But still dont get it to work...

Comment: @JeppePepp: You need `using System.Data.Entity;` at the beginning of your code file to get the lambda extension method available.